# Does a logical matrix representing sets have a name or special properties?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, boolean-algebra

Imagine a collection of separate objects and several sets.

[image: Example of sets and objects]

These sets can be represented using a **logical matrix**.

$M = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Each line corresponds to a set, and each column corresponds to an object.

So $M_{i,j} = 1$ if $Set_i$ contains $Object_j$, else $0$.

I wondered if this kind of matrix, used to represent sets, had a special name?
And if, in addition, there was some interesting properties?

For example, to represent a graph, one can use an adjacency matrix, which is a logical matrix too. By raising it to the n-th power, each $x_{i,j}$ obtained indicates the number of existing n-length paths from i to j.

I am in search of similar property (which may be about subset or superset for example), or a name to this matrix that would allow me to further my research.

Answer (score 1):

In computer science, this representation of subsets is known under various names: [bit array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array),
[bit string](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/ftpdir/scheme-7.4/doc-html/scheme_10.html), bitmap, bitset or bit vector. It is extremely compact and Boolean operations can be implemented in a very efficient way, but it is limited to small sets.

From this point of view, your matrices might be called *arrays of bitsets*.